# Page full of widgets?

Tags: widgets

Is it possible to create a page which is just lots of widgets? most WP sites I see the widgets are in the sidebars, but I want a page which is just widgets and nothing else. The theme I'm currently using allows me to add columns or a table to a page but I don't know if it's possible (in any theme) to then add widgets to those columns or table cells?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? Please post your current code.

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet, it's just I've never seen that on a WP page, so wondered if it was even possible. But how would you put a widget into a normal page? is it possible via the admin? or maybe you have to download another plugin or it's down to the theme/shortcodes?

Comment: Please research the Codex for general instructions for implementing Widgets and Dynamic Sidebars. WPSE is not well-suited for this sort of question.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently this is not as much of a mystery as I first thought.

Here's 2 links.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-wordpress-widgets-in-post-and-page-content/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/widgets-on-pages/